# Visual Studio Docker failing on node.js not being in path when it is

Tags: node.js, docker

I have installed Docker on my PC - Docker Desktop - and have created a git repository in Azure Devops for my SPA (Aurelia). I find I have, instead of IISExpress for running the project, I have "Docker". I click on "Docker" to run it and it goes all the way through and then I get the following exception. Seems simple enough that I dont have node.js in my path except that it is.. I have googled this and there are a couple of questions on adding Node.. So I added it to the user variables.. I have added it to the System variables. I then deleted all entries and re-installed Node.. which then added node to the path itself. I then re-started and again re-ran the project - first in IISExpress - success - then in Docker and you can see the exception again.. I have no idea why when Node is on the machine and in the path and its still throwing an exception??

[image]

[image]

```
    System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)
   at JobsLedgerAPI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\AURELIA\1. - JOBSLEDGER SPA\JobsLedgerSPA\JobsLedgerAPI\Startup.cs:line 44

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned `on my PC`, I believe that running Node.js app on your PC needs [iisnode module](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html). Its configuration in your [`web.config`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config) takes care of running the Node.js process and the main file `Node.exe` executes (e.g. `server.js`/`main.js`/`app.js`) and the whole app lifecycle.

Example as follows:

```
    <handlers>
          <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
<!--...-->

    <iisnode
          nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" 
          interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
```

Hope it helps. Same module also helps running the Node.js app on Azure (docker infrastructure might be using same module as well).

Additional Refs: [Installing iisnode On Windows](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode)

PS: 
You may have to install appropriate iisnode module version as per your IIS version (Express/regular etc.).

I have Windows 7 64-bit OS w/ IIS 7.5. I installed [iisnode](https://github.com/azure/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.21/iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64.msi). After that, I followed the instructions as listed on [this page](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode). Then it loaded my Node.js app on `http://localhost:82/`. You also might have to give the user `IIS_IUSRS` proper permissions (`READ`) to the folder where you are hosting your Node.js web app and its parent folder as well (welcome new tricks!).

My working `web.config` from the node web app on localhost:82 follows. Please edit as per your machine.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application
        to be handled by the iisnode module -->

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

<globalModules>
    <add name="iisnode" image="C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\iisnode.dll" />
</globalModules>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="sendToNode">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Barebones example `server.js` follows. Please install Express for Node.js unless it is already installed.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Express is working on IISNode!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Yes I am cursed.. IISnode will not install. It says "There was a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A script required for this to install to complete could not be run... surely this should just install..??