# iisnode 7.x (64x) full Setup install fails with a message saying a script could not be run

Tags: docker, iisnode

As a result of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863433/visual-studio-docker-failing-on-node-js-not-being-in-path-when-it-is) I wrote a little earlier I person was kind enough to write an answer. He suggested installing iisnode to fix a problem where node.js was in the path but docker couldnt find it.. However, on his suggestion I downloaded iisnode for iis 7.x(x64) and proceeded to run it... and with the luck I am having I got the following error..

> There was a problem with this Windows Install package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I have no idea how to solve this.. any ideas.. I have entered docker for this as I suspect this problem has occured for others when they tried to run a dotnet core SPA project...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad English!
I had this issue while i was working with "**Plesk**" but maybe my solution works for you or others.
First you should go to **"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config"**.
Make a backup of **"applicationHost.config"** somewhere.
Then remove every line that contains **"iisnode"** in that file.
Then try to install **"iisnode"** again. if it does not work, restart your OS and try again.
If it does not work again, restore your backup and restart your OS and i don't know how you can fix it, Sorry :((

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows Server 2022 and this was the solution for me.  Thanks!